# Custom tkinter slider

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

I am trying to make an user friendly interface for a project that I am planning on completing. I want to use a slider but the default slider doesn't fit my needs aesthetically.

I have already designed what I would like my slider to look like:

| Example 1 | Example 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Example 1] | [image: Example 2] |

I know the basics of coding in tkinter but I am stuck on how to set the tkinter slider to look different. If anyone is able to help that would be truly appreciated.

Comment: You have 2 options: use a `tkinter.Canvas` to create your own slider widget or use something other than `tkinter`. `tkinter`'s sliders aren't very customisable. The first one will take a lot of time but the second one might take even more time if you already completed most of your project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I simulate a Scrollbar in tkInter Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348742/how-do-i-simulate-a-scrollbar-in-tkinter-canvas)